# Is power amplifying just a name for using high power on amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier

I mean I know bjt or mosfet amplifier circuits lets say amplifying 10mVpp to 1Vpp with low currents. However I don't know can the same topology be also used with lets say 8 9 volts out and with 1A or so current. Is this kind of amplifying refers to power amplifying and is the only difference I should use high power dissipation rated transistors instead of normal 2n222 bjt for example.

Comment: For power amplification often other topologies are used in addition to meattier transistors, in order to improve efficiency. Instead of wasteful class A amplifiers you see for instance class AB, B or D.

Answer (score 3):

The name "Power amplifier" (PA) is used in many different contexts:

- As an Audio amplifier driving a loudspeaker or loudspeakers or headphones
- As the amplifier delivering an RF (Radio Frequency) signal to an antenna, your phone will have several of these.
- Any other application where a signal needs to be amplified so that it has more power such that it can be used for wherever that power is needed.

Some PAs use the same topology as a "normal" amplifier.

Many opamps use an output stage that has a similar circuit structure as a discrete (build with individual transistors) audio power amplifier. I would not call the output stage of most opamps a "Power amplifier".

**Some** amplifier designs based on a small signal transistors (like the 2N222) can be re-used as a more powerful amplifier just by replacing the transistors with "bigger" ones and adjusting some resistor values. Note that this will work for **some** designs, not all of them. Often it is simply better to re-use an existing design using power transistors or (if you can) design your own power amplifier.

Comment: Thanks, if you look the question below, I have described the case where I think I should use a power amplification but I am not sure. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469405/utilizing-a-signal-in-the-needed-form-to-drive-a-load